# How to Read/Generate+Read file in thread-safe way in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm using **.NET Framework v4.5**.

I'm creating kind of image resizer by using MagickImage library.

---

### Use case:

User uploads big image (4k*4k pixels) and use it in different places with different size (200*200 pixels, 1200*1200 pixels).

So I'm generating such images on demand by resizing big one and storing them on the disk.

**Case with concurrency:** User upload image, and then couple of users request the thumbnail of this image. In that moment each of user requests starts to create resized thumbnail because it is not exists yet. When the first thread which finished resizing save it to disk. All another threads will get exception because of the file is already in use.

---

Before that **it was working with single thread** and there was no need for a thread safety.

But now its gonna be used in a web-based project, and **concurrent requests are possible as well**.

Current implementation is looks like:

```
if (!FileExists(cachedImageFilepath))
{
    byte[] resizedImage = _imageResizer.ResizeImage(originalImageFilepath, width, height);

    _physicalFileManager.WriteToFile(cachedImageFilepath, resizedImage);
}

return cachedImageFilepath;
```

The easies way is simply to use lock around this operation but in this case Resizer will resize only one image in single period of time.

Another variant that I see is to create something like a lock mechanism which will lock by string key.

But anyway I see a problem with double checking if the file exists after releasing lock like:

```
if (!FileExists(cachedImageFilepath)){
  lock(lockObjects[lockKey]){
    if (!FileExists(cachedImageFilepath)){

    }
  }
}
```

**Is there a good way or even .NET mechanism to do such thing without overhead?**

Comment: You have different thread concurrently accessing the same file?

Comment: Define *concurent request* please? You can use file-based locking mechanism (open write file exclusively first, the first who opens it - do the job, others - skip), meaning you do not need in-memory locking.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yep, and the problem is then they both starting to creat thumbnail with same size (saving the same file)

Comment: Should they be updating the *same file*? Does that make sense?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov that make no sense, only first one should generate image, the second one should just wait till image is ready and then just return path to this image like "return cachedImageFilepath;"

Comment: mutex is the solution

Comment: If you are worried about filenames from the users colliding you could generate temporary filenames instead using the System.IO namespace.

Comment: You could create a temp file and rename it to the target name once you finished. Discard the temp file if renaming fails because the target file already exists. Should work on Windows + NTFS, but I'm not 100% sure if this approach is safe on certain filesystems/operating systems.

Comment: Your last example is good. The double check is needed.

Comment: Why not just create all the sizes when the original image is uploaded?

Comment: I would recommend to separate concurrency and storage layers. This will simplify the code and make concurrency layer independent of the file system.
About concurrency. I suppose, that optimal implementation can't be based on locking mechanism only, waiting for events is required also.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you need is a thread-safe thumbnail manager. I.e. a class that itself understands how to coordinate access to the files.

A simple version of that might look like this:

```
class ThumbnailManager
{
    private Dictionary<Tuple<string, int, int>, string> _thumbnails =
        new Dictionary<Tuple<string, int, int>, string>();
    private Dictionary<Tuple<string, int, int>, Task<string>> _workers =
        new Dictionary<Tuple<string, int, int>, Task<string>>();
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public async Task<string> RetrieveThumbnail(string originalFile, int width, int height)
    {
        Tuple<string, int, int> key = Tuple.Create(originalFile, width, height);
        Task task;

        lock (_lock)
        {
            string fileName;

            if (_thumbnails.TryGetValue(key, out fileName))
            {
                return fileName;
            }

            if (!_workers.TryGetValue(key, out task))
            {
                task = Task.Run(() => ResizeFile(originalFile, width, height));
                _workers[key] = task;
            }
        }

        string result = await task;

        lock (_lock)
        {
            _thumbnails[key] = result;
            _workers.Remove(key);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

string ResizeFile(string originalImageFilepath, int width, int height)
{
    string cachedImageFilepath = GenerateCachedImageFilepath(originalImageFilepath);

    if (!FileExists(cachedImageFilepath))
    {
        byte[] resizedImage = _imageResizer.ResizeImage(originalImageFilepath, width, height);

        _physicalFileManager.WriteToFile(cachedImageFilepath, resizedImage);
    }

    return cachedImageFilepath;
}
```

In other words, first the manager checks to see if it knows about the necessary file. If it does, then that means the file's already been created and it just returns the path.

If it doesn't, then the next thing it checks is to see whether the creation of the necessary file is already in progress. After all, no point in making the same file more than once! If it's not already in progress, then it starts a `Task` to make the file. If it already is in progress, then it simply retrieves the `Task` representing that operation.

In either case, the `Task` representing the operation is awaited. The method returns at that point; when the operation is done, the method resumes execution, adding the name of the resulting file to the dictionary of completed files, and removing the completed task from the in-progress dictionary.

Naturally, it being an `async` method, the correct way for the caller to use this is for it itself to use `await` when calling it, so that the method can complete asynchronously if needed without blocking the calling thread. There's not enough context in your question to know exactly what that would look like, but I presume you can figure that part out.

Comment: But I would like not to keep any information about thumbnails in the memory, because that is temporary files, and I will have a lot of them.

Comment: @U10: I don't see them as temporary files - you haven't said anything about deleting them later. You could potentially remove the _thumbnails dictionary and check for an *expected* file name (on the file system) after checking whether or not anything's currently doing the thumbnailing (in which case the file may exist but be in the process of being written). That would have the added benefit of handling the case where the web app restarts.

Comment: @U10: the temporary nature wasn't mentioned in your question. On what condition would a file be removed? Can you remove the entry from the _thumbnails dictionary when that happens? Note that the code already handles the restart scenario, as the resize just returns the name if the file already exists. But Jon is correct...you could just skip having the _thumbnails dictionary at all (it's a minor optimization), and simply check for the presence of the file itself as that check.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry, I've not mentioned the condition when files will be removed, basically that will not happens, but any way I don't want to store _thumbnails collection in memory, so I gonna make check in file system.

Comment: @U10: okay, that's fine. The above will still work...just replace the dictionary check with the file system check (and then you can skip it in the thumbnail generation method).